# What unexpected behaviour can returning a pointer to a char array member cause?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Okay, so. I've been working on a class project (we haven't covered std::string and std::vector yet though obviously I know about them) to construct a time clock of sorts. The main portion of the program expects time and date values as formatted c-strings (e.g. "12:45:45", "12/12/12" etc.), and I probably could have kept things simple by storing them the same way in my basic class. But, I didn't.

Instead I did this:

```
class UsageEntry {
public:
    ....

    typedef     time_t  TimeType;
    typedef     int     IDType;

    ...
    // none of these getters are thread safe
    // furthermore, the char* the getters return should be used immediately
    // and then discarded: its contents will be modified on the next call
    // to any of these functions.

    const char*         getUserID();
    const char*         getDate();
    const char*         getTimeIn();
    const char*         getTimeOut();

private:
    IDType      m_id;
    TimeType    m_timeIn;
    TimeType    m_timeOut;

    char        m_buf[LEN_MAX];
};
```

And one of the getters (they all do basically the same thing):

```
const char* UsageEntry::getDate()
{
    strftime(m_buf, LEN_OF_DATE, "%D", localtime(&m_timeIn));
    return m_buf;
}
```

And here is a function that uses this pointer:

```
// ==== TDataSet::writeOut ====================================================
// writes an entry to the output file
void TDataSet::writeOut(int index, FILE* outFile)
{
    // because of the m_buf kludge, this cannot be a single
    // call to fprintf
    fprintf(outFile, "%s,", m_data[index].getUserID());
    fprintf(outFile, "%s,", m_data[index].getDate());
    fprintf(outFile, "%s,", m_data[index].getTimeIn());
    fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", m_data[index].getTimeOut());
    fflush(outFile);
} // end of TDataSet::writeOut
```

How much trouble will this cause? Or to look at it from another angle, what other sorts of interesting and !!FUN!! behaviour can this cause? And, finally, what can be done to fix it (besides the obvious solution of using strings/vectors instead)?

Somewhat related: How do the C++ library functions that do similar things handle this? e.g. localtime() returns a pointer to a struct tm object, which somehow survives the end of that function call at least long enough to be used by strftime.

Comment: Can you edit your title so that it summarizes your question body?  What is your actual question, in 10 or so words?

Comment: I generally find questions of the "how can I solve X with anything but the appropriate solution" unhelpful. Just use the appropriate tools for the job.

Comment: @KerrekSB Similarly, I find questions where any mention of alternative solutions is drowned out by a torrent of "this is the proper way to do this" unhelpful. The proper way may not always be possible. If I could use the proper way in this case, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @Wlerin Unlike most of the questions you are probably referring to, you were clear in your constraints, and this is good. All of the answers below are of good quality. In any case this *is* probably a more appropriate question for Code Review than SO. What you are describing occurs less on CR because these sites serve different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough information to determine if it will cause trouble because you do not show how you use it. As long as you document the caveats and keep them in mind when using your class, there won't be issues.

There are some common gotchas to watch out for, but hopefully these are common sense:

- Deleting the `UsageEntry` will invalidate the pointers returned by your getters, since those buffers will be deleted too. (This is especially easy to run into if using locally declared `UsageEntry`s, as in [MadScienceDream's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26593747/616460).) If this is a risk, callers should create their own copy of the string. Document this.
- It does not look like `m_timeIn` is `const`, and therefore it may change. Calling the getter will modify the internal buffer and these changes will be visible to anything that has that pointer. If this is a risk, callers should create their own copy of the string. Document this.
- Your getters are neither reentrant nor thread-safe. Document this.

It would be safer to have the caller supply a destination buffer and length as a parameter. The function can return a pointer to that buffer for convenience. This is how e.g. [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) works.

A strong API can avoid issues. Failing that, good documentation and common sense can also reduce the chance of issues. Behavior is only unexpected if nobody expects it, this is why documentation about the behavior is important: It generally eliminates unexpected behavior.

Think of it like the "CAUTION: HOT SURFACE" warning on top of a toaster oven. You could design the toaster oven with insulation on top so that an accident *can't* happen. Failing that, the least you can do is put a warning label on it and there *probably won't* be an accident. If there's neither insulation nor a warning, eventually somebody *will* burn themselves.

---

Now that you've edited your question to show some documentation in the header, many of the initial risks have been reduced. This was a good change to make.

---

Here is an example of how your usage would change if user-supplied buffers were used (and a pointer to that buffer returned):

```
// ==== TDataSet::writeOut ====================================================
// writes an entry to the output file
void TDataSet::writeOut(int index, FILE* outFile)
{
    char userId[LEN_MAX], date[LEN_MAX], timeIn[LEN_MAX], timeOut[LEN_MAX];
    fprintf(outFile, "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
        m_data[index].getUserID(userId, sizeof(userId)),
        m_data[index].getDate(date, sizeof(date)),
        m_data[index].getTimeIn(timeIn, sizeof(timeIn)),
        m_data[index].getTimeOut(timeOut, sizeof(timeOut))
    );
    fflush(outFile);
} // end of TDataSet::writeOut
```

Comment: Ah, yes, documentation. We don't have proper documentation yet, but I suppose I should include the comments that are already in the header file.

Comment: @Wlerin Behavior is only unexpected if nobody expects it, this is why documentation about the behavior is important: It eliminates unexpected behavior.

Comment: The only other "gotcha" I can think of, which I don't yet know how to address, is that const UsageEntries can't do anything.

Comment: @Wlerin They can if you declare the getter `const` and the internal buffer [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv), which essentially it is: Changing its contents doesn't change the semantic value of the `UsageEntry` itself. But if you start doing this too often, it could be a red flag that there is a more solid option (e.g. a user-supplied buffer).

Comment: When implementing a version using a user-supplied buffer, considering that the size is known at compile time (from several defined constants), is there any reason to include the second (size_t) parameter, rather than just hard-coding it into the function itself? Well, I suppose the buffer passed in might be too small... but if someone is making that error, he might also pass in the wrong size anyway.

Comment: e.g. now I'm doing this: `const char* getUserID (char* dest = NULL, size_t size = LEN_OF_ID) const;`
using the (now static) mutable buffer if no pointer is supplied, otherwise writing to the given destination.

Comment: @Wlerin Similar to the above, passing the size vs. assuming it again just comes down to how much you want to mitigate the risk of a potential problem. If you assume a buffer size, document the assumption thoroughly. If the amount of data you are copying is known ahead of time then assuming a buffer size is not necessarily problematic, as long as you document (see [`ctime`](http://bit.ly/1uHyn0X) for example). If on the other hand it's up in the air, it's usually best to pass the size (e.g. [`strcpy_s`](http://1.usa.gov/1tlU6Eg), article also covers some of your question).

Comment: @Wlerin So it's your call, really, just be aware of the assumptions you are making and always document clearly and thoroughly. It's up to you to determine if a risk is significant or not based on your specific situation, the context your code is being used in, the type of programmer you expect to be using your code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here, as the main problem with most pointer based code, is the issue of ownership. The problem is the following:

```
  const char* val;
  {
     UsageEntry ue;
     val = ue.getDate();
  }//ue goes out of scope
  std::cout << val << std::endl;//SEGFAULT (maybe, really nasal demons)
```

Because `val` is actually owned by `ue`, you shoot yourself in the foot if they exist in different scopes. You COULD document this, but it is oh-so-much simpler to pass the buffer in as an argument (just like the `strftime` function does).

(Thanks to odedsh below for pointing this one out)

Another issue is that subsequent calls will blow away the info gained. The example odesh used was

```
fprintf(outFile, "%s\n%s",ue.getUserID(), ue.getDate());
```

but the problem is more pervasive:

```
const char* id = ue.getUserID();
const char* date = ue.getDate();//Changes id!
```

This violates the "Principal of Least Astonishment" becuase...well, its weird.

This design also breaks the rule-of-thumb that each class should do exactly one thing. In this case, `UsageEntry` both provides accessors to get the formatted time as a string, AND manages that strings buffer.

Comment: Also FUN will be had if used like this: `fprintf(outFile, "%s\n%s", ue.getUserID(), ue.getDate());

Since if I understand correctly both write to the same memory address so the result will be surprising

Comment: @odesh Indeed. And on that note, apparently fprintf processes its arguments in reverse order >_>

Comment: @Wlerin the order fprintf processes its arguments is irrelevant since the arguments it will find on its stack are `const char*` pointers. The order in which getUserID() / getDate() methods is called is undefined and can be different from one implementation to the next

Comment: The line you have marked as "segfault" is probably not going to segfault; the destructor for `ue` is unlikely to do much at all, so the stack memory it occupied is probably going to be in the same state and it will *appear* to work. Having said that, a segfault is definitely possible, but I would prefer to label that line "undefined behavior" since that's really what it is. It might segfault, it might work (for some definition of "work"), or it might do something else entirely.

Comment: @Wlerin Off topic: Yes, it does, on Windows `printf` uses the `__cdecl` calling convention which specifies that arguments are passed right-to-left. It evaluates them in that order, as well.

Comment: @odedsh Well, it's relevant to what output you get in the end (though it will be wrong regardless). But yes, I suppose you're right that it depends on what version of the library you're using.

Comment: @JasonC well as far as I know Order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. (see C99 §6.5.2.2 1025)

However I agree that __cdecl would require pushing the arguments to the stack at a certain order and it is likely to be the order the functions will be evaluated (since additional registers would be required otherwise) I don't think the order is guaranteed though.

Comment: @odedsh thanks for pointing that out, added to my answer cus this length of comments is likely to get cleaned.

Comment: @odedsh Yup, that's correct, it is not specified or guaranteed. MS's compiler just consistently has always done it that way for `__cdecl` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> How much trouble will this cause? Or to look at it from another angle,
> what other sorts of interesting and !!FUN!! behaviour can this cause?
> And, finally, what can be done to fix it (besides the obvious solution
> of using strings/vectors instead)?

Well there is nothing very FUN here, it just means that the results of your getter cannot outlive the corresponding instance of `UsageEntry` or you have a dangling pointer.

> How do the C++ library functions that do similar things handle this?
> e.g. localtime() returns a pointer to a struct tm object, which
> somehow survives the end of that function call at least long enough to
> be used by strftime.

[The documentation of localtime says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime):

> **Return value**
>
> pointer to a static internal std::tm object on success, or NULL otherwise. The structure may be shared between
> std::gmtime, std::localtime, and std::ctime, and may be overwritten on
> each invocation.

Comment: +1 Awareness and proper documentation are really the key to avoiding issues here, when a safe API design is not provided.

Comment: I've always wondered why on earth they decided to go with that design, though that may be a "too broad" question on itself. Any insight?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams My guess would be that it is some kind of balance avoiding both the copy of the structure and dynamic allocation. Since `localtime` is a function with a very punctual usage, this design seems to give the simplest usage of all, you don't even have to provide the structure yourself as a parameter.